# 500 Internal Server Error on calling JHipster register api deployed on aws while its working for locally deployed app

Tags: amazon-web-services, retrofit, jhipster

For the same req payloads(while using register api i.e., a HTTP post method):

```
{login: "hot123", email: "jad@hf.wj", password: "*******", langKey: "en"}
```

I am getting two different result.
On locally deployed app,it gives success while on one deployed on aws it gives 500 server error :

```
 {"message":"error.internalServerError","description":"Internal server error","fieldErrors":null}
```

Please give some pointers.

Note - I am using retrofit for making network calls.

Server Logs :

2016-11-12 17:31:07.824 ERROR 23390 --- [ost-startStop-1] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]

2016-11-19 14:48:40.597  WARN 23390 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'POST' not supported

2016-11-21 09:21:36.359 DEBUG 23390 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] com.xyz.myapp.web.rest.UserResource  : REST request to save User : ManagedUserVM{id=null, createdBy=null, createdDate=null, lastModifiedBy='null', lastModifiedDate=null} UserDTO{login='newuser', firstName='first', lastName='last', email='first@last.com', activated=true, langKey='en', authorities=[ROLE_USER]}

Comment: Please show the server logs

Comment: @Marziou And when I am making another post api calls,I get the same error mentioned above,but it gets inserted into my database.

Comment: Your logs do not seem to contain any log statements from your JHipster app, are you sure you configured them correctly or looked at right place?

Comment: @Marziou I guess I am missing something very basic...but these are some of the logs which I found worth sharing..Please let me know which logs do you need.

Comment: First log says you haven't configured an elasticsearch cluster. In dev, it's an embbedded cluster, in prod it must be an external one already configured in your platform

Comment: But that does not create any 500 error, right?And the interesting thing is that all other post api calls give the same error but they are getting anyhow inserted into database.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with elasticsearch. You can use Metric system such as JHipster Console (ELK), or modify your ExceptionTranslator to provide the exceptions message instead of the fixed "internal error" string, so you can look for the exakt exception, which is off in production profile

Comment: @DavidSteiman Thank you David.. elasticsearch was the main culprit..removed it and now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have not configured nodes for elasticsearch on aws.That's why in jhipster boilerplate created for your application,whenever anyline like:

```
entitySearchRepository.save(entity);
entitySearchRepository.delete(id);
```

is executed,it gives you the error `AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes :`